# How to handle a dropped DSMB spool at depth

Tags: safety, scuba-diving, safety-standards

When technical diving, you usually will deploy your Delayed Surface Marker Buoy prior to your first decompression  stop (eg 70ft).  If you drop while attempting to deploy and it unravels at depth, what is the safest way to address this?

Comment: This feels like something you should be discussing with an actual in person dive instructor, and potentially even practice in a controlled environment (ex. pool). You may get a satisfactory answer on here, but especially given the high consequences of a mistake, reading a written account may be insufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Assume you mean you've sent up the SMB but dropped the spool.

It happens to the best of us.  If the spool's relatively heavy,  such as the Apeks spools,  it'll head off down faster than you can descend.  Some lighter plastic spools descend more slowly and you can catch them.

Retrieving the spool depends on how much time you have and the depth,  i.e. will the spool hit the bottom or not.  If you've loads of time, as may be the case at deco,  you can wrap the line around something to pull up the spool, then you can unwrap the line from whatever you've wrapped the line around and rewind it back on to the spool.  (Have wrapped the line around my hand before,  but had to be ready to cut the line should something bad have happend.  It took 20 mins to wind it up then re-wind it back on to the spool from my hand.)

If you're in shallower water with a long line then another alternative is to use a double-ender or something weighty to form a loop which you then pull up the line from the unwinding spool and then onto the loop where the double-ender will drop down.  Hopefully you'll pull up the line before the spool snags on the bottom.  Once you've retrieved the spool it's then relatively easy to wind it back on to the spool and recover your double-ender.  Benefit here is it'll halve the length of the line (less the depth) and it's a lot safer than wrapping it around your hand.